# How to do formulas for multiple dataframes at once?

Tags: r, dataframe

Lets say i have two dataframes: `DF1` and `DF2` and both have variables `x` and `y`.

I want to create following new dataframes with a loop function:

```
Df1.1 <- DF1$X*DF1$Y
Df1.2 <- DF1$X/DF1$Y
Df2.1 <- DF2$X*DF2$Y
Df2.2 <- DF2$X/DF2$Y
```

How could I use loop to create new dataframes and apply formulas for them? could not find any answers that regard these two at the same time.

Comment: Why so many dataframes? Why not put all these results in one dataframe with multiple columns?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create a function and put everything into a list and loop the function using `lapply`

Data

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:5,
                  y = 101:105)
df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                  y = 51:60)
```

Code

```
exfun <- function(df){
  mult <- df[,"x"] * df[,"y"]
  divi <- df[,"x"] / df[,"y"]
  list(mult, divi)
}

lapply(list(df1, df2), exfun)
```

This output returns a nested list - each outer position represents the input data frame, each of which has two inner lists representing the multiplication (first) and division (second) operations.

If you needed to put a lot of data frames in a list, if they all shared the same patterns (ie, "df"), you could do:

```
l <- do.call("list", mget(grep("df", names(.GlobalEnv), value = TRUE)))

lapply(l, exfun)
```

Which will get all the objects from the global environment with "df" into a list

Lastly, if you truly wanted to assign your new values to the global environment with "dfx.1", "dfx.2" as in the question:

```
dfs <- grep("df", names(.GlobalEnv), value = TRUE)

for(i in dfs){
  assign(paste0(i, ".1"), get(i)[,1] * get(i)[,2])
  assign(paste0(i, ".2"), get(i)[,1] / get(i)[,2])
}
```

Comment: @JH1 See the edit and if that works for you, if not I will update

Comment: It seems to be working but i ran into another problem, the  dataframes in the list have different number of variables x and y, for example Df1 could have only data for 10 x and 10 y while Df2 could have 12 x and 12 y. It creates error incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem as long as `x` and `y` are from the dame data frame - I edited the sample data I created to have different lengths demonstrate that it still works. There must be something specific in your actual data that's going on, but each df can certainly have different lengths in this approach

Comment: Was mistake on my part! thanks! Another thing i was wondering can i do the same but filtering the data and not do calculation? for example in df1.1 could have highest 50% of x values for df1 and  df1.2 lowest 50% of x values for df1?

Comment: yes, you can change the operations in `exfun` to do whatever you'd like, it doesn't have to be multiplication/division. I just did those because they were the examples provided. but you can add anything to the user-defined function.